# How can I configure JPA repositories for different DataSources in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource, spring-repositories

I use spring boot app. I select data from DB by JDBC DataSource and Repositories. Some query by JDBS and some queries by Repositories. My DB configure RAC and has 2 instance. I connect to db by `129.0.0.2` but this URL balanced between `129.0.0.3(1 instance) and 129.0.0.4(2instance)`. All queries execute  with `129.0.0.2` but some queries I need to execute only on one instance. I created 3 datasources:

```
@Bean(name = "primary")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "second")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDatasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "three")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.threeDatasource")
    public DataSource threeDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

And configure them in application.properties. Then I can write

```
@Qualifier("primary")DataSource dataSource
```

or

```
@Qualifier("second")DataSource dataSource
```

But what DataSource will use when I execute repositories query?

Answer (score 1):

Create two configurations classes like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.package.repositories.datasource1", 
   entityManagerFactoryRef = entityManagerFactory1)
class DataSource1Configuration {

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory1(@Qualifier("primary") DataSource primary) {
    // … create entity manager factory based on primary source
  }
}
```

Second configuration class would be obviously similar but tailored to use secondary datasource

BTW, since Java 8, it may also be possible to have two annotations of type  (two `@EnableJpaRepositories` in this case) on same class. So it may also work with one configuration class, but two `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotations.

Comment: Can you share link to oficial documentation or article where recomended this solution? or it yourself solution?

Comment: I believe this should work from what I know about Spring Data JPA. Didn't try it myself. As talking to two databases from one Spring Boot application is kind of architecture smell, I doubt you would find a lot of resources about it.

Comment: make sense to talk to two databases when you will want to separate read from writes on the same table(s).

Comment: @sherelock, do this separation in one JVM? Sorry that doesn't make any sense to me. If you would want to separate reads from writes (e.g. Lambda architecture), you would do it from two separate services/JVMs. Thus this case would not happen, because each service would use single JDBC connection.

Comment: In a large project that is mixing entities from source A and B in multiple packages it´s impossible to manage responsible data sources from a central point. I´d love to have an annotation to define the data source on each repository instead